# Parsing a string and returning an array

Tags: java, bluej

Heres my code that takes a string and returns an array of the ascii values for each character in the array in order. Compile error is 'array required, but java.lang.String found'

```
public class Q1E {
    int[] stringToCodes(String characters){
        int characterLength= length(characters);
        int[] array=new int[characterLength];
        for(int i=0;i<characterLength;i++) {
            array[i] =(int) characters[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to return `array` at the end of your method.

Comment: change `length(characters);` with `characters.length();`otherwise your code won't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use array syntax on a String, use `character.charAt(i)`instead. Also, you need to return the array at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses Unicode/UTF-16 for strings, not ASCII.

If want to restrict your method to processing characters in the ASCII range, it should throw an exception when it encounters one outside that range.

If you want a sequence of "character codes" (aka codepoints), you have to use the `String.codePointAt()` at method. Because `String` holds a counted sequences of UTF-16 code-units and there might be one or two code-units per codepoint, you only know that `String.length()` is an upper bound of the number of codepoints in advance.

```
public class Q1E {
  int[] stringToCodes(String s) {
    int[] codepoints = new int[s.length()]; // there might be fewer 
    int count = 0;
    for(int cp, i = 0; i < s.length(); i += Character.charCount(cp)) {
        cp = s.codePointAt(i);
        // for debugging, output in Unicode stylized format
        System.out.println(String.format(
            cp < 0x10000 ? "U+%04X" : "U+%05X", cp));
        codepoints[count++] = cp;
    }
    int[] array = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(codepoints, count);
    return array;
  }
}
```

Try it with this Wikipedia link on an English word:

```
stringToCodes("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Résumé");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to have a few bugs, it's [`String#length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) and I would suggest you add a `null` check. Finally (since `characters` isn't an array), I think you want to use [`String#charAt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29)

```
int[] stringToCodes(String characters) {
    int characterLength = 0;
    if (characters != null) {
        characterLength = characters.length();
    }
    int[] array = new int[characterLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < characterLength; i++) {
        array[i] = characters.charAt(i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Of course, you could shorten it with a ternary

```
int characterLength = (characters != null) ? characters.length() : 0;
int[] array = new int[characterLength];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class Test {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

     int []ascii=stringToCodes("abcdef");
     for(int i=0;i<ascii.length;i++){
      System.out.println(ascii[i]);
     }

 }
  public static int [] stringToCodes(String characters){
     int []ascii=new int[characters.length()];

    for(int i=0;i<characters.length();i++){
      ascii[i]=(int)characters.charAt(i);
    }
 return ascii;
}
```

}